# Masonry not working quite right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm working on a Wordpress project that features a glossary page with 3 columns. I'm trying to use Masonry to get all the entries to fit together nicely, which is almost working, but not quite.

Here's the page in question: http://ratherbrilliant.com/staging/starstruck/category/glossary/browse-A/

It's a usual Wordpress setup meaning that there are a number of articles nested in a container div.

```
<div id="glossary-content">
  <article class="post">article content</article>
  <article class="post">article content</article>
  <article>article content</article>
</div>
```

The articles are percentage width and floated:

```
    body.category-glossary article {
    width: 26%;
    padding: 0 3% 0 4%;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float: left;
}
```

I'm using just the the default Masonry setup, though I've tried all sorts of options to get it to work.

```
$('body.category-glossary #glossary-content').masonry({
    itemSelector : '.post', 
});
```

It's almost working, but if you scroll down, you'll see a giant gap between the first entry and the one below it. I simply cannot get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your code? Can you gice more information?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added more information.

Comment: For starters you are missing another set of `});` in your JS

Comment: I rewrote my js and now it's working. That must have been it. Thanks.

Comment: Good, problem solved.